# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY for Google Map example

Tags: android, google-maps

While running my googlemap example I'm getting errors like

```
[TIMESTAMP - googlemap] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[TIMESTAMP - googlemap] Please check logcat output for more details.
[TIMESTAMP - googlemap] Launch canceled!
```

and in logcat I haven't got anything.. please gimme the solution if anyone knows..

thanx in advance..

Comment: are u using google map api v2?if yes are u added google-playservices-lib in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your manifest file inside the `application` tag and create avd with target `Google APIs (Google Inc.)

```
<application
        <uses-library android:required="true" 
                      android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
```

Your emulator AVD does not have `Google Maps`. Create an emulator AVD with a "Target" that has "`Google APIs (Google Inc.)`" in the name.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your manifest :

```
<application
        <uses-library android:required="true" 
                      android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```